# Nexus 7: Unable to install factory image, stuck in < waiting for any device >

Tags: adb, twrp, fastboot, nexus-7, bootloader

I want to restore factory android on my Nexus 7 2012 WiFi.

I'm following [the official guide](https://developers.google.com/android/images).

I start the device in fastboot mode by executiong:

```
adb reboot bootloader
```

This works well.
But **when I run any command that uses** `fastboot` **the execution gets stuck**, eg:

```
$ fastboot oem unlock
< waiting for any device >
```

The same issue with `flash-all.sh`.

I also noticed that if I run

```
adb devices
```

it doesn't list the tablet. However it gets listed if I run the same command after entering Recovery Mode (I have TWRP recovery).

**More details/preconditions:** I used to have CianogenMod on the device but I smashed it by mistake (I removed Android in recovery mode instead of simply wiping the data). I can't find the CianogenMod image anymore on LinageOS site (there is only Nexus 2013 available) so I'm trying to install at least what is available.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that `fastboot` didn't see the device without `sudo`.

To make `flash-all.sh` work I replaced every `fastboot` call with `sudo $(which fastboot)` like was [suggested in this post](https://askubuntu.com/a/705541/710246).

Answer (score 0):

Well, the device is detected in ADB only, you probably haven't installed [fastboot](https://www.androidcentral.com/android-z-what-fastboot) drivers. `< waiting for any device >` means that the computer is waiting for a device in fastboot mode.

Download the drivers from [this page](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/win-usb.html) then install. `fastboot oem unlock` should work now.

[Learn](https://bbs.elephone.hk/thread-3683-1-1.html#.WqMbl3njKUk) the difference between these two protocols (ADB and Fastboot).

This [question](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/58187/adb-can-discover-devices-but-not-fastboot) may also help.

Comment: Acoording to the link you’ve posted the drivers are needed only for windows, but I’m using Ubuntu. Anyway I’ll try tomorow.

Comment: This could help , I guess: https://developer.android.com/studio/run/device.html

Comment: You didn't mention anything about your OS, so I assumed you were on Windows... Oh skipped the flash_all.sh part. Sorry

Comment: I installed `android-tools-adb` package, however I can't enable USB debugging (not sure if it is really needed) as I don't have Android on the device. I still end up with `< waiting for any device >`

Comment: Your fastboot isn't working, phone is not being detected. Are you sure you're in Bootloader ? Any screenshot?

Comment: https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/58187/adb-can-discover-devices-but-not-fastboot

Comment: Thank you. I'm running fastboot for sure ( `lsusb` shows that the device is in fastboot mode). I've found that the problem is somehow related to sudo access  - `fastboot devices` works with root.