# How to I unlock the bootloader on an Honor 7s?

Tags: bootloader, huawei

I've attempted to unlock the bootloader using the fastboot method using ADB tools on my pc, which have yielded no results. I open powershell in the folder containing all the ADB tools and run "adb devices". My phone (not yet in fastboot) shows up. I than run adb reboot bootloader and my phone opens up into fastboot. All my screen shows in that is fastboot FRP unlock. Than running fastboot devices yields no output and no following commands work. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can we consider Huawei phones as unrootable?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/232190/can-we-consider-huawei-phones-as-unrootable)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ADB can discover devices but not fastboot](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/58187/adb-can-discover-devices-but-not-fastboot)

Comment: No, I've tried everything mentioned and nothing works

Comment: I have disabled driver signature before that comment, but I had not done some of those things within that guide. I will try them out

Comment: No, this guide dosent work either. Should I just take it that my phone is not rootable? I've tried every possibility now

Comment: I've managed to get it working after reinstalling a driver and it all works up to the fastboot oem unlock part. How do I get the code for my bootloader? DC unlock costs money and its no longer available on the Huawei website. I do not plan on spending anything

Comment: Of course one must buy 4 credits on https://www.dc-unlocker.com/buy